# How to parse information from Stripe session id

Tags: stripe-payments

Its been quite sometime since I have done any coding or HTML/Java stuff. I got sucked into a charity job and am kinda stuck. I need to recording data from a transaction on strip and I have it sending back the session information but I am struggling to retrieve can anybody help.

This is the return I get from Stripe
/checkoutcomplete.cfm?session_id=cs_test_a1eqLKW0sTTvicyXHvKqZAAuKceff7ELMGJEMWAZr1OvyhBmOolJjI2YY9

An example of how to get that information back from that would be amazing I cannot get it done with the strip docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your endpoint that handles `/checkoutcomplete.cfm`, you can call Stripe API to [retrieve](https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) the checkout session object with [line_items](https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) [expanded](https://docs.stripe.com/api/expanding_objects), so that you can use these information to update your system.

Comment: I tried putting that exact code in a <script> but i couldnt get it to work...

Comment: No, You should run the code in your backend. There's no frontend API to retrieve a checkout session object.

Answer (score 0):

Well after some work I was able to get it working !

```
<cfparam name="URL.session_id" default="">
<cfhttp method = "GET" url="https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/#url.session_id#/line_items" result = "content_1">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer sk_test_aHhoYVOnsayNSIleB1ETUCSq00vUOS9YVQ">
</cfhttp>
<CFSET content_1 = DeserializeJSON(content_1.filecontent)>
<cfdump var="#content_1#">
```

Comment: Note your secret key "sk_test_xxx" in this message, you should likely edit the answer to remove it and roll the key https://docs.stripe.com/keys#rolling-keys